# Requests with python 3.3

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

How to install [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install)  to use with python 3.3.

I use mac, and have both python 3.3 and 2.7.1 installed. Paths.

```
2.7.1 : 

which python
/usr/bin/python

3.3:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin
```

I tried these to install

```
curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3 distribute_setup.py
sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/python3 -m easy_install pip
sudo /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pip install requests
```

the last step gives error:

```
 File "./requests/utils.py", line 22, in <module>

    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header

  File "./requests/compat.py", line 112, in <module>

    from .packages import chardet2 as chardet

ImportError: cannot import name chardet2
```

I tried setting the PYTHONPATH to:

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages
[~/tmp] $
```

still same error.

I also tried after installing chardet2; but

```
   $ python3.3
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 01:25:11) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import chardet2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'chardet2'
>>>
```

### EDIT: Detailed pip.log

```
 Skipping link http://octodex.github.com/ (from https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/site/terms (from https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/site/privacy (from https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/security (from https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests); not a file
  Using version 0.14.2 (newest of versions: 0.14.2, 0.14.1, 0.14.0, 0.13.9, 0.13.8, 0.13.7, 0.13.6, 0.13.5, 0.13.4, 0.13.3, 0.13.2, 0.13.1, 0.13.0, 0.12.1, 0.12.0, 0.11.2, 0.11.1, 0.10.8, 0.10.7, 0.10.6, 0.10.4, 0.10.3, 0.10.2, 0.10.1, 0.10.0, 0.9.3, 0.9.2, 0.9.1, 0.9.0, 0.8.9, 0.8.8, 0.8.7, 0.8.6, 0.8.5, 0.8.4, 0.8.3, 0.8.2, 0.8.1, 0.8.0, 0.7.6, 0.7.5, 0.7.4, 0.7.3, 0.7.2, 0.7.1, 0.7.0, 0.6.6, 0.6.5, 0.6.4, 0.6.3, 0.6.2, 0.6.1, 0.6.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.0, 0.3.4, 0.3.3, 0.3.2, 0.3.1, 0.3.0, 0.2.4, 0.2.3, 0.2.2, 0.2.1, 0.2.0)
  Downloading from URL http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/requests/requests-0.14.2.tar.gz#md5=488508ba3e8270992ad5b3fb54d364ca (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package requests

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

      File "/private/var/folders/fc/k8b9ds214nv4lqv2x4395khc0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging377147531338803949.tmp/requests/setup.py", line 6, in <module>

        import requests

      File "./requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>

        from . import utils

      File "./requests/utils.py", line 22, in <module>

        from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header

      File "./requests/compat.py", line 112, in <module>

        from .packages import chardet2 as chardet

    ImportError: cannot import name chardet2

    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/fc/k8b9ds214nv4lqv2x4395khc0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging377147531338803949.tmp/requests/setup.py", line 6, in <module>

    import requests

  File "./requests/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>

    from . import utils

  File "./requests/utils.py", line 22, in <module>

    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header

  File "./requests/compat.py", line 112, in <module>

    from .packages import chardet2 as chardet

ImportError: cannot import name chardet2

----------------------------------------

Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/fc/k8b9ds214nv4lqv2x4395khc0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging377147531338803949.tmp/requests

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py3.3.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 107, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py3.3.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 256, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py3.3.egg/pip/req.py", line 1042, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py3.3.egg/pip/req.py", line 236, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py3.3.egg/pip/util.py", line 612, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/fc/k8b9ds214nv4lqv2x4395khc0000gn/T/pycharm-packaging377147531338803949.tmp/requests
```

Comment: `chardet2` is part of the `requests` distribution, so you test it with `from requests.packages import chardet2`.

Comment: do you have pip installed on your mac?

Comment: @rofls: Look at the install log, pip is being installed there.

Comment: >>> from requests.packages import chardet2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'requests'

Comment: Make sure you don't have a file permissions problem.  See if it works using `sudo python3.3`.

Comment: At the Cheese Shop page (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests), it shows that the current version has "build status failing". Try downloading either the previous version, or the current tarball from github (as described in the requests documentation), or probably just `pip-3.3 install git+https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests` (untested, but I'd give even odds it works).

Comment: great that solved it. please put it as answer so I may accept

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [Cheese Shop page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) currently shows "build status failing" for version 0.14.2. And it looks like downloading this tarball and trying to build/test/install it does actually fail with 3.3. This isn't *too* surprising, since 0.14.1 was the first version to work with 3.3, and probably not many people are using it with 3.3 yet…

So, what can you do about it (beyond reporting a bug in the appropriate way)? Two choices:

- Get the 0.14.1 tarball and install that.
- Get the latest source and install that.

The second one is actually easier, and probably better (when it works), and it's actually suggested in [the documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/) for Requests.

However, what the documentation doesn't tell you is that you can get the benefits and simplicity of `pip` while still using the latest source:

```
pip-3.3 install git+https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests
```

I just tested this, and it worked fine, and (as expected) gave me the exact same results as following the instructions in the Requests documentation.